# I want to open play store with flutter WebView application using flutter web view plugin for the WebView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I have an error in my flutter code.

how can I solve this error, flutter URL launcher is not working.

Comment: You Have any Answer So please tell  me about this

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the full error logs and the code snippet causing this error?

Comment: I guess you are looking for this,
https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher

More logs would help understand the actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open google play store inside web view then you can simply do

```
 import 'dart:io';

 import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

 class WebViewExample extends StatefulWidget {
   @override
   WebViewExampleState createState() => WebViewExampleState();
 }

 class WebViewExampleState extends State<WebViewExample> {
   @override
   void initState() {
     super.initState();
     // Enable virtual display.
     if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = AndroidWebView();
   }

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://play.google.com/store/apps',
     );
   }
 }
```

check the [webview_flutter package](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) documentation for more info